# What is it called when the main melody is playing in a different time signature from the harmony?

Tags: harmony, terminology, time-signatures, melody, meter

For example, in the [Phantasy Star Online Intro song](https://youtube.com/embed/_kyRrIvdImA?start=40&end=80), the main melody starts to play in 3/4 time, whereas the overall song (and the harmony) remains playing in 4/4 time. (starts after 10 seconds, at the 0:50 mark). Technically, you can probably say it's 4/4 time, or 12/12 time if you want to be silly, but it's clear that the melody and harmony here are seemingly playing with different time signatures, only syncing up every few measures (4 in this case).

Does this have a name or any way it's referred to commonly? I can't really think of any other songs that do it off the top of my head, so perhaps it's not notable enough....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When two parts are playing in different time signatures, it's called **polymeter**.

*However, that isn't what's happening in this piece.*

Both parts are in 4/4 time, but at the 0:50 mark, the accompaniment part speeds up, and the two parts play at different tempos. This is called **polytempo**.

From about 0:30 to 0:50, the tempo clocks in at 84 BPM. At 0:52, the singer sustains her note on "world", which allows the accompaniment to begin speeding up. Thereafter, the melodic parts stay at 84 BPM, but the accompaniment gradually speeds up from 84 BPM to about 90 BPM before rejoining the melody at the original tempo.

This particular effect is a cousin of **phasing**, a technique credited to the composer Steven Reich, in which two or more instruments begin in rhythmic unison, but gradually move out of phase with each other until eventually syncing up at the end of the piece.

---

For more on

- Polymeter: [Polymeter vs Polyrhythm](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/10488/70803)
- Polytempo: [What is it called when a music has two concurrent tempos](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/30524/70803)
- Phasing: [Is there a term for repeated melodies of different length](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/115653/70803)
- All of the above: [What is rhythmic counterpoint?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/105561/70803)
- A question very similar to this one: [What’s going on with the rhythm in the first half of Spiral Staircase by Luke Vibert](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/75211/70803)

Comment: I can hear the string melody get wayyyy ahead of the beat at 0:54, and I can hear everything come back together leading up to 1:14. BUT. if you follow it closely, you will see that the melody does not gain or lose any beats in that time, relative to the percussion.  The part was just way ahead and finally settled back to being in time.  It's a lot more like an ensemble tear than anything else, and I think describing what's happening in terms of "phase" and "phase locking" will be more useful than describing in terms of "tempo"

Comment: ("Phase" is a term I have heard used, but I'm not sure if it is the accepted term- basically, where you are in the beat.  Ahead? Behind? Right on it?)

Comment: And this effect is completely seperate from what OP is describing- there is indeed a 6-note ostinato in 4/4.

Comment: The strings get a bit ahead of the the beat, but calling that 'polytempo' is a bit far-fetched. I agree with @Edward that OP is hearing the eighth-note strings ostinato with the accents **1**23**4**56**7**8 which could cause a naive listener to think the strings are playing  in 3/8..

Comment: @PiedPiper or even a sophisticated listener who is prone to confusion.  But reading this answer, I wonder to what extent Reich and his contemporaries were inspired by mensural canons, for example by Johannes Ockeghem.

Comment: @Edward , imho your comments are the correct answer.

Comment: @Edward Both the melody and the 6-note ostinato are in 4/4; however, the ostinato gradually speeds up from 84bpm to 90bpm. With phasing, as Reich implements it, the tempi stay the same, except for a small delay in the phased parts at the end of each cycle.

Comment: @KrisVanBael See my comment to Edward. If you measure the tempo, you'll find that the melody is constant and the ostinato is not.

Comment: @ Edward @PiedPiper you it it right on the head, I think! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Aaron tempo might drift somewhat and the parts aren’t always locked. But still… each part has the same number of bars and beats (as Edward pointed out). No phasing in my opinion.

Comment: @KrisVanBael I don't understand your comment. I've consistently commented that it's not phasing, only that it's "a cousin of". It's Edward who first suggested that phasing was the better explanation.

Comment: @Aaron indeed, thank you for pointing that out.   With “speeding up & rejoining” and the reference to phasing, I thought that you implied the ostinato was skipping a beat. But indeed you never said that. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's anything terribly complicated going on here.   The tempo and beat don't change.  There's a  whole-note thing going on, and an 8th-note one, grouped in threes.  We could call it 'cross-rhythm.

Answer (score 0):

One term is "polyrhythm." It also applies when several parts move in different rhythms.